# (linux) bash script to run script after delay

Tags: linux, bash, cron

having a problem getting the following to work. I've added a cron job on reboot  as follows

```
@reboot /home/pi/bash_script
```

to execute a bash script containing the following

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/sleep 60 && /usr/bin/python /home/pi/foo.py
```

I've also done a chmod x to the file to make it executable.

But it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone recognize any errors in my script or suggest what troubleshooting steps I might take?

This is the error log I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/foo.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/foo.py", line 65, in main
    root = tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1712, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sy$
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: Is it the Bash script that's failing or the Python?  Does `/home/pi/foo.py` exist when the script is run?  (Is `/home` mounted?  This may be irrelevant if `/home` is part of the root file system.)  Add `set -x; exec 2>/tmp/pi-bash.$$` before the `/bin/sleep` line; run it; look for a file `/tmp/pi-bash.NNNN` (where the N's are digits) and see what, if anything, it says.  Does the Python script rely on environment variables that are either unset or set differently in the context where they're run?  You could add `env >&2` to the tracing code to spit out the environment.

Comment: Anything reported in _syslog_?

Comment: thanks will try the above. Running the bash script directly from LXTerminal works, ie my Python script runs and creates the gui.

Comment: ok closer!. Something to do with the DISPLAY environment variable. I get the SAME error if i try and run my Python remotely via SSH.

Comment: I've added the log error to my original question above...using tKinter for my GUI.

Comment: A `cron` job does not run under your normal desktop environment, and so it can't see your `DISPLAY` variable - what would you expect it to do if you weren't there to log in immediately when it rebooted? Your GUI (Gnome/KDE/whatever) probably has facilities to autostart certain things on login - use those instead of `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have this in your script instead.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec bash -l -c '/bin/sleep 60 && /usr/bin/python /home/pi/foo.py'
```

Or as a crontab command:

```
/bin/bash -l -c '/bin/sleep 60 && /usr/bin/python /home/pi/foo.py'
```

Comment: thanks, will try. does it matter if I use #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/sh   ? also when editing the cron job, shoudl i use sudo?

Comment: @eco_bach If necessary as user `pi` yes probably.

Comment: still no cigar, tried both options...I think for my next step i should do a test to ensure my cron job executes properly on reboot

Comment: @eco_bach Perhaps it's good to update your post with your crontab entry and tell that you wanted to run python as `pi` user.

Comment: Ive ended up using a workaround...editing the Leafpad autostart file  http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=11256

Comment: rather, the simplest solution. I thought it wasn't working before but it was my baudrate that was incorrect and was skipping data.